# How can i select a pre-existing element in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use a pre-existing element to create a chart with d3.

If I create the element from scratch like this:

```
 var svgContainer = d3.select("#content")
                      .append('div')
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", size.x)
                      .attr("height", size.y)
                      .attr('id', 'chart');
```

Things work fine, bit if instead I have a pre-existing element that looks like this:

```
<div>
   <svg id="chart" width="1400" height="800">
   </svg>
</div>
```

and then try to select like this:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
```

things don't work anymore.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag3W2/

Comment: Turns out it's a duh solution. d3 <script> needs to go in _after_ the chart <svg>. Thanks @felix

Comment: Yep, you can only select an element if it exists at the moment you are trying to select it.

Comment: Could you please post and the answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The d3  needs to go in after the chart . An element can only be selected if it exists at the moment you are trying to select it. Thanks @felix.